# How to make a div extend to the bottom of the page without getting too tall

Tags: html, css

I have a div near the bottom of my page that I want to extend all the way to the very bottom edge of the window so that the background color of the page can not be seen below it. Initially, depending on the size screen that the page was rendered on, a small sliver of the background color was still visible below the div. By adding

```
html, body, .wrapper {
    height: 100%;
}
```

to my CSS ("wrapper" being the class of the div in question), I fixed *that* issue, but now the div has a height of around 500px (it varies based on the window size) despite the only element in the div having a total height of 132px (which does not change regardless of window size). Because of the positioning of the div, this 500px height makes the page stretch and now there is a large blank space at the bottom of my page, underneath the content inside the div.

I used Chrome's developer tools to inspect the HTML, body, and div tags and there is no strange padding/margins and no defined height (other than the "100%" that I set). If you'd like more code I can gladly provide more but since I don't know exactly what the problem is I didn't know what would be relevant (plus I'm using bootstrap so finding all of the relevant CSS can be a pain sometimes). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you recreate the issue using https://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: @Huangism  I did my best, it's a very oversimplified version but https://jsfiddle.net/754s67ur/

It does have a similar problem to my page which is that the div.table has the same height as the body, even though there are two divs above the table inside the body (if that makes sense). My goal is to make the div take up the **remaining** space (stretch to the bottom of the window), not automatically resize to be the same height as the body.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use flexbox to have the .wrapper, or .table in your example, div fill up the remaining height.

For the parent element (in your example, body) set `display: flex; flex-direction: column;`

For the element that you want to expand (.wrapper or .table) set `flex-grow: 1`.

Your Example Updated: https://jsfiddle.net/754s67ur/2/

Comment: Thanks a ton! That fixed the problem with the div at the bottom of my page! ... but it also made the left and right margins on the second div (the "body of my page" in the example), which are set to "auto", very large. I don't want to manually set the margins to a smaller value because I want them to vary based on window size and it looked good before with auto margins. Do you know how I might fix this?

Comment: I'm not seeing where the margins were set to auto in the fiddle. Can you provide an example of how it was before? The original example and the update look very similar, only difference was the reset of html and body elements to 0 margin and padding.

Comment: I'm talking about on my actual web page now. I didn't include the margins in the fiddle because they weren't relevant before. My middle div on my web page has `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;`. Before I applied the flex settings, the content was 1140px wide with 15px padding and 375px margins on both sides. After applying the flex settings, the content shrank to 707px wide with 15px padding and 591.5px margins. Any idea what about the flex display might cause this and how I can fix it?

Comment: How was the width being set to 1140px before? Can you provide an updated example in the fiddle?Try removing the auto margins on that div and see if that reverts the outcome to how you had it before, that way it will span the full width of the container, which I believe is what you want.

Comment: This is what I was saying about Bootstrap making it hard to find all of the relevant CSS. The max-width is set based on the width of the window using bootstrap (the "container" class specifically), so the relevant line would be something like: `.container { max-width: 1170px; }` and the container class would be applied to the second div.

Comment: Look at this example, https://jsfiddle.net/754s67ur/5/, and toggle the commented `margin: 0 auto;` rule. Is one of these the desired output? Hard to guess at what you are asking for here.

Comment: It's hard to recreate in a fiddle because again, I don't know what exactly is causing it, but when I set `display: flex;` on my `<body>` tag, it drastically increases the size of my auto margins of my second div. I'm not really sure how to show it to you and there's a lot of CSS for my site because I'm using Bootstrap. I wasn't sure if you were aware of any quirks of the flex display that would cause something like that to happen.

Answer (score 1):

I have updated the fiddle you posted in the comments to add background colors and removed paddings and margins to better visualize the problem [here](https://jsfiddle.net/754s67ur/4/).

What you need is the CSS `calc` function to have your `.table` div take up 100% of the page MINUS the nav and body content of your page (represented by the `<p>` in your fiddle).

In the fiddle they are both 18px, so combined it's 36px and that is what I need to minus from the 100%. So the style would look like this:

```
height: calc(100% - 36px);
```

This is how you calculate the remaining space. But this only works for static height elements. Here is a fiddle of the [solution](https://jsfiddle.net/754s67ur/3/).

Comment: This might be a stretch of a question but is it possible to make the "36px" a variable of sorts so that I wouldn't have to manually change that number if I make an edit to my page that changes the height of the nav or body?

Comment: Unfortunately no. This is the drawback to this solution. If you want something with dynamic heights you will either have to use `flexbox` or use javascript to calculate the heights and set it that way.

Comment: Oh well, thanks anyway. Do you happen to know why when I try to use `display: flex`, the left and right margins (which are auto margins) get really big for my main body div? (If you look at my response to the other comment there's some more info)

Comment: Off the top of my head.... have you tried setting a `min-width` of your main body div? Is that do-able?

Comment: I want the content to resize so that's not an ideal solution. I might just have to do something like that (or use your height calc suggestion).